# Moment.js Add a time in minutes to a time in hours:minutes

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Consider the user inputs,

```
var firstTrainTime = 12:00 //input as **hours:minutes**
var frequency = 30 //input as any number (user could for instance 
enter 1345 minutes) of **minutes**
```

Both of these variables are input as strings.

I'm attempting to use Moment.js to produce the "next arrival" time of the train so that it outputs

```
var arrival = 12:30 //this will be in 24hr format ("HH:mm")
```

My code:

```
var a = moment(firstTrainTime, "HH:mm");
console.log("this is firstTrainTime " + a);

var b = moment(freq, "m");
console.log("this is freq " + b)

var nextArrival = a.from(b);
console.log("this is nextArrival " + nextArrival);

nextArrival = moment().format("HH:mm");
console.log("this is nextArrival " + nextArrival);
```

Var's a & b return moment objects - but, then when I run the "from" method on them it returns "12 hours from now" in console.

I'm coding this for a webapp using javascript/jquery.

Thanks so much! Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
var firstTrainTime = 12:00 //input as **hours:minutes**
var frequency = 30         //input as any number (user could for instance enter 1345 minutes) of **minutes**

moment(firstTrainTime, 'HH:mm').add(frequency, 'minutes').format("HH:mm")
//"12:30"
```

Documentation on #add() for moment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Comment: Thanks @Lance. I'll give that a shot!

Comment: So when I tried that line it returned in console: 
momentjs-activity.html:26 
r {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "12:00", _f: "HH:mm", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}
_d
:
Sun Jun 11 2017 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
_f
:
"HH:mm"
_i
:
"12:00"
_isAMomentObject
:
true
_isUTC
:
false
_isValid
:
true
_locale
:
C
_pf
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: do i need to change it to UTC time first?

Comment: So that means you console.log'ed the moment object. You need to console.log the info returned from the `.format()` method, since this returns a string based on the format you provide.

Comment: So would I write that console.log(.format);  --thanks for the patience with my noobishness :). I had put it in a variable and console logged the entire line.

Comment: The following will log "12:30" to the console, not the moment object: `console.log(moment(firstTrainTime, 'HH:mm').add(frequency, 'minutes').format("HH:mm"))`